# Weird inheritance bug iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, inheritance

Okay so i decided to move my code for my **UITableView delegates** into another class. a subclass if you will, A subclass so that it would make it easier to access all the elements my **Cellforrowwithindexpath** function does within said subclass.

But now there is a slight issue...

It works fine, as far as the **UItableView** is concerned, But then when i tried to use the **navigation controller** to push a view on top, it did not work, i then discovered that self...Within my main class was actually an instance of my **subclass**...What? so self is not actually equal to self...

Can anyone give me any insight as to what i am doing so colossally wrong here?

**EDIT**: So i changed it to instead be a subclass to a delegate and it works fine, just in case anyone else runs into This issue, But i am still confused as to why it was happening in the first place...

**Code:**

```
@interface OpenGameList : MainMenuViewContoller <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{

}

@end
```

In my **MainMenuViewController's viewDidLoad** function

```
_openGameList = [[OpenGameList alloc] init];
_openGameList.delegate = self;

friendsTable.delegate = _openGameList;
friendsTable.dataSource = _openGameList;
```

And than after that it seems that any use of self in **MainMenuViewController** is equal to **OpenGameList** hence why using `[[fromView navigationController] pushViewController:toView animated:NO];` does not work

Comment: Without seeing any code, no one can help answer this.

Comment: Please don't use code formatting for emphasis.

Comment: ...Okay i was down voted by someone who suggested an edit that put the code formatting for emphasis, at least i assume so. and now another person suggests i don't? I mean critique my format if you will but a down vote for a rather trivial thing is a bit harsh isn't it?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. My comment was to the person who edited your formatting to begin with. I didn't vote down the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` always points to the object that was actually instantiated – the most derived class.

When you have an instance of a subclass, and you send a message to `self`, the subclass's implementation will always be invoked if there is one. It doesn't matter whether or not you're in the superclass's implementation file or the subclass's implementation file.

This is an essential for polymorphism: it's what allows subclasses to override the behavior of a parent class. Take `-[UIView drawRect:]` for example. To invoke the drawing code for subclasses, when code in `UIView` invokes `[self drawRect:]` it's the subclass's drawing implementation which needs to be called.

It might help to remember that superclasses and subclasses aren't parent and child objects, but less and more specific types which apply to the same object. A `UITableView` is also a `UIScrollView`, `UIView`, and `NSObject`, but when you make one, there is **one object which is all of those things, and `self` always refers to that one.**

Comment: Your second paragraph is a bit misleading. I know what you're saying but I think it could be worded better. At the moment it looks like you're suggesting that if you've subclassed an object then instances of the superclass may also execute subclass code.

Comment: I can see why that would be essential to polymorphism, it just seems a little odd how calling self from the parent class would refer to the child...nevertheless I fixed(or rather tried a different method) it and it's working now, It seems to me that if you can use a delegate to do something over sub-classing you should do that unless sub-classing is absolutely necessary

Comment: I rewrote the second paragraph and added a fourth.